# SELECT DISTINCT in Bolt CMS

Tags: sql, bolt-cms

Is there a way to get unique values of the field of the specified content type in Bolt CMS (e.g. all unique dates of event content type)? Something like SELECT DISTINCT.

I know it's possible to create an extension for that but I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have access to query the database directly, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT distinct `contenttype`, `taxonomytype` FROM `bolt_taxonomy` WHERE `contenttype` = 'entries'
```

Which, on my very fresh install of Bolt 3.3.6 yields these results:

```
contenttype taxonomytype    
entries     categories
entries     tags
```

So you would replace "entries" with "events" and "bolt_taxonomy" with the appropriate table you are looking at.